# Wenzhixin bootstrap-table with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, bootstrap-table

We are trying to data-bind click events to bootstrap-table and cant get it to work. We have tried binding towards buttons, a hrefs, tr's and td's but it doesnt fire.

We can successfully populate the table with data from our database via knockout tho.

```
        <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: listOfCustomers-->
        <tr class="clickable-row">
            <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></td>
            <td class="text"><button type="button" class="bananen" onclick="App.CustomersScreen.onAfterRenderFunc();"></button></td>
            <td class="text">{{ name }}</td>
            <td class="text">{{ town }}</td>
            <td class="text">{{ mail }}</td>
            <td class="text">{{ phone }}</td>
            <td class="text">Motor</td>
            <td class="text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></td>
            <td data-visible="false"
                data-switchable="false" class="hidden">{{ id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
```

I hope you understand the question

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are using Handlebars templating, you have an `onclick`, and Bootstrap may be manipulating the DOM as well. Can you make a simple example that we can run as a fiddle or snippet?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using the wrong data-binding syntax.

Knockout uses `data-bind` attributes, whereas your example HTML looks as if it's expecting a JavaScript templating engine like handlebars.

Now, Knockout allows you to replace its rendering/templating engine with whatever you like, so it's possible to use an engine such as handlebars, but as you haven't said that in your question it's my guess that you *haven't* swapped out Knockout's templating engine.

If I'm right then your HTML should be something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: listOfCustomers-->
        <tr class="clickable-row">
            <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></td>
            <td class="text"><button type="button" class="bananen" onclick="App.CustomersScreen.onAfterRenderFunc();"></button></td>
            <td class="text" data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td class="text" data-bind="text: town"></td>
            <td class="text" data-bind="text: mail"></td>
            <td class="text" data-bind="text: phone"></td>
            <td class="text">Motor</td>
            <td class="text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></td>
            <td data-visible="false"
        data-switchable="false" class="hidden" data-bind="text: id"></td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```